# Exception Catch Failing? Visual Studio mysteriously hangs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, exception

So I've got this exception defined, protected constructors, static constructor methods (so all the exceptions are generated with the same formatting and I don't have to fight in the constructors. Anyway, this is besides the point... (not my issue? let's leave that alone k?)

```
public class ValidationException : Exception
{
   // Constructors
   public static ValidationException Create(IEnumerable<string> errors)
   {
      // yadda, yadda, yadda, build exception message, pass in errors, configure, shabang...
      return vex; // vex is the created exception
   }
}
```

Then I have the following code as part of an **NHibernate** `PreInsertEventListener`.

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> validationErrors;
if (TryValidateObject(obj, out validationErrors)) return;

throw ValidationException.Create(validationErrors);
```

Then in my implementation i have this:

```
try
{
   Save();
}
catch (ValidationException)
{
   UserMessage.CreateMessage("A Validation error has occured. Please contact your system administrator / software support.").Show();
}
```

The save function basically does all my final manipulation in NHibernate and executes `Flush()` on the data session.

So basically as an **overview**:

1. `Save()` is called.
2. `Flush()` is called in **NHibernate**
3. NHibernate's pipeline is executed
4. My `PreInsertEventListener` event is called.
5. `ValidationException.Create(...)` is called which returns a `ValidationException`. This is then thrown from the `PreInsertEventListener`

Now here's the real doosey. The expected behaviour is that the `catch` block fires, and catches my `ValidationException`, prompting my user message dialog to show up.

**But what actually happens** is that vstudio & my app in debug hang for about 1 minute. 100% unresponsive, window signals ignored, windows ready to kick the process in the butt, then it finally unsticks and tells me an "Unhandled ValidationException was thrown", at the exact line that im throwing my exception. So somehow this isn't getting caught.

When i run this outside of the debugger, the app insta-fails.

Am i missing something? This all should be executed from the same thread, the call stack is pretty danm clear:

```
> MyApp.Core.dll!MyApp.Core.Validation.ValidationHelper.DoValidateObject(object obj = {MyApp.Data.Entities.Administration.Career}) Line 153 C#
  MyApp.Data.Entities.dll!MyApp.Data.Entities.Entity.Validate(out System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary> validationErrors = null, bool throwExceptions = true) Line 73 + 0xa bytes C#
  MyApp.Data.dll!MyApp.Data.NHibernate.EntityValidateListener.OnPreInsert(NHibernate.Event.PreInsertEvent event = {NHibernate.Event.PreInsertEvent}) Line 23 + 0x30 bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.PreInsert() Line 151 + 0x42 bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute() Line 44 + 0xd bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(NHibernate.Action.IExecutable executable = {EntityInsertAction[MyApp.Data.Entities.Administration.Career#24cda829-e829-4228-997f-55ff890d6eec]}) Line 130 + 0x37 bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(System.Collections.IList list = Count = 1) Line 113 + 0x10 bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() Line 146 + 0x13 bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(NHibernate.Event.IEventSource session = {NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl}) Line 240 + 0x3d bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(NHibernate.Event.FlushEvent event = {NHibernate.Event.FlushEvent}) Line 19 + 0x1b bytes C#
  NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() Line 1187 + 0x92 bytes C#
  MyApp.Data.dll!MyApp.Data.AbstractDataSession.Flush() Line 57 + 0x36 bytes C#
  MyApp.UIFramework.dll!MyApp.UIFramework.ViewModel.EntitiesViewModel.Save() Line 110 + 0x2c bytes C#
  ManagerWPF.exe!ManagerWPF.Modules.Careers.ViewModels.CareersViewModel.HandleSave() Line 274 + 0x11 bytes C#
  ManagerWPF.exe!ManagerWPF.Modules.Careers.ViewModels.CareersViewModel.get_SaveCommand.AnonymousMethod(object x = null) Line 263 + 0xa bytes C#
  MyApp.UIFramework.dll!MyApp.UIFramework.Commands.DelegateCommand.Execute(object parameter = null) Line 50 + 0x24 bytes C#
```

Comment: Are you throwing the exception on a different thread?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NHibernate, but the symptoms sound to me like the Exception is being thrown on a different Thread and not being marshaled back to the thread that calls `Save()`.

Comment: @0xA3: As I stated, no it's not being thrown from another thread, I just finished walking through NHibernate in .NET Reflector to make sure NHibernate wasn't spinning up any asynchronous calls.

Comment: @0xA3, @Toby: I agree with both of you that the symptoms point in that direction, but he appears to have a clear call stack that goes from his function call to the exception-throwing code.

Comment: @Aren: If the call stack shows the full call path, then it's not being executed on another thread.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: As I suspected, thank you for confirming this for me.

Comment: Your `ValidationException` sample doesn't appear to be deriving from `Exception`.  This isn't necessarily a requirement, but it might be related...

Comment: @Dan Puzey: It is, but in my haste to represent it in shorthand (above) I forgot the inheritance declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that all happens on the same thread (this is what it looks like from your call stack) then it could be a namespace conflict, too.

Are the `ValidationException` types being thrown and the one that should be catch identical, i.e. in the same namespace? Seems that NHibernate already defines a `ValidationException` and you also define your own `ValidationException`.

To fix such a problem you have several options:

- Get rid of your own custom exception and use the one provided by the framework
- Rename your exception class
- Use fully qualified names, e.g. `MyApp.Exceptions.ValidationException`
- Use an alias name when importing a namespace: `using MyEx = MyApp.Exceptions;`

Comment: Oh my god, I cannot believe it was this simple. You were totally on the ball, there's some appendix code in a different namespace, but with the same name (`ValidationException`). This code written a long time ago by another developer, slated for removal. **Now what I'd like to know** is why the hell vstudio hangs for 1-2 minutes when this exception is thrown?

Comment: @Aren B: I don't know exactly what keeps Visual Studio busy, but from my experience it is perfectly normal that the Visual Studio debugger reacts slow when it encounters an unhandled exception. Tough usually this is a matter of around 5-10 seconds and not in the range of minutes...